# Box collider not stopping particle collision?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Box Collider with `Is Trigger = true` to stop particles at an area. I am adding this under Particle Collision with Type `Planes`. Unfortunately, the particles do not seem to collide at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have set Is Trigger = true, if you want collision then set it false.

Comment: triggers mean it does just that, doesnt stop anything..

Comment: @observer and thank you I had not realized it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Box Collider to stop objects, you need to set `Is Trigger = false`.

Also, by definition a collision involves a rigidbody because it's a physics event. Therefore, I would recommend adding a Rigidbody component to the obsticle.